# if scenario not working in ruby

Tags: ruby

I just started learning ruby. Can someone let me know why this is not running? Thank you.

```
greeting_preference = true

until greeting_preference

Puts "How should I greet you?"

greeting_preference = gets.chomp

if greeting_preference == "Bonjour!"
    puts "Bonjour!"
    greeting_preference = true

if greeting_preference == "Hola!"
    puts "Hola!"
    greeting_preference = true

if greeting_preference == "in Afrikaans"
    puts "Hallo!"
    greeting_preference = true
else
    puts "Uh, hi?"
end
```

Comment: define "not working"

Comment: Do you get an error or what happens? looks to me like you are missing `end` keyword in `until` and `if` loops. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm

Comment: I bet for an unexpected end of input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to end the until statement.

The until statement **Executes code while conditional is false**, so **until !greeting_preference**

```
   greeting_preference = false

   until greeting_preference do

   puts "How should I greet you?"

   greeting_preference = gets.chomp

   if greeting_preference == "Bonjour!"
      puts "Bonjour!"
      greeting_preference = true
   elsif
      greeting_preference == "Hola!"
      puts "Hola!"
      greeting_preference = true
   elsif
      greeting_preference == "in Afrikaans"
      puts "Hallo!"
      greeting_preference = true
   else
      puts "Uh, hi?"
   end

   end
```

Comment: It's an endless loop.

Comment: @EricDuminil In the question he never changes the **greeting_preference** to false , so I think he wants an endless loop.

Comment: It's hard to say with the original code. What would be the  use of `greeting_preference = true`, then?

Comment: Thank you. I'm doing this as an exercise for a class. I tried this but, it doesn't just end after end. For example, I answered Bonjour! and it came back with Uh, hi?

Comment: @Emika I just understood what you want to achieve. I will update my answer again.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you just `end` your `until`. Your `if`s and `if-else`s need an `end` as well

```
if greeting_preference == "Bonjour!"
    puts "Bonjour!"
    greeting_preference = true
end
```

if-else

```
if condition
  puts "something"
else
  puts "something else"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

put enclosing `end` with if-else

```
greeting_preference = true
while greeting_preference
    puts "How should I greet you?"
    greeting_preference = gets.chomp
    if greeting_preference == "Bonjour!"
        puts "Bonjour!"
        greeting_preference = true
    end
    if greeting_preference == "Hola!"
        puts "Hola!"
        greeting_preference = true
    end
    if greeting_preference == "in Afrikaans"
        puts "Hallo!"
        greeting_preference = true
    else
        puts "Uh, hi?"
    end
end
```

Better use `case` statement :

```
greeting_preference = true
while greeting_preference
    puts "How should I greet you?"
    msg = gets.chomp
    puts case msg
        when "Bonjour!" 
            "Bonjour!"
        when "Hola!" 
            "Hola!"
        when "in Afrikaans" 
            "Hallo!"
        else
            greeting_preference = false
            "Uh, hi?"
        end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Just tried it. After response, it asks again"How should I greet you?" I do like the code tho. Very clean.

Answer (score 1):

You can write FORTRAN in any language. :)

Your code would be easier with a [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html). It's basically a dictionary in which you can define keys (greetings) and values (answers). If the key isn't found, ask again!

```
greetings = {
  'Bonjour!' => 'Bonjour!',
  'Hola!' => 'Hola!',
  'in Afrikaans' => 'Hallo!'
}

puts 'How should I greet you?'
puts "(possible choices are #{greetings.keys})"

until greeting = greetings[gets.chomp]
  puts 'Uh, hi?'
end

puts greeting
```

It outputs:

```
How should I greet you?
(possible choices are ["Bonjour!", "Hola!", "in Afrikaans"])
Hello?
Uh, hi?
Hi!
Uh, hi?
Hola!
Hola!
```

Comment: Thank you. Taking a Ruby class now.